# why do class constants as default keys in arrays turn to numerical keys in php?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, class, constants

I would like to save the user settings when to send an email. To achieve this I was going to make use of my system's class constants of the Mailing Class and use its constants as array key values. But for some reason the keys are turned into numerical indexes and the match on runtime with class constants doesnt work anymore. When I use a single string instead, its working as expected..

This is an example of the class with the output given:
http://pastie.org/2541980

Comment: Are you sure that no other part of the code interferes with this `$sendEmail` attribute? I ran your code (without the `use` or `extends` statements) and I can't reproduce your bug. In your sample, you set 5 string keys, and you get 6 numerical keys, so it's not just a conversion. I guess there's another part of your code that's interfering. Did you try to change your attribute name?

Comment: my code is in reality a bit longer with much more constants, I just wanted to keep the example clean and oversaw the 6th numerical output on the 2nd var_dump() - so this is just a typo. sorry. I updated the paste

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it like this? The constants seem to resemble flags -- a more efficient way of handling those is to map them to a number, ideally using binary operators. That way, you can 'turn on' all applicable flags, resulting in just one integer -- easier to store and easier to pass around.

Check this out: http://life-of-brian.com/2008/04/binary-code-bitwise-operators-php/

Comment: basically the only reason I'm using strings is to make it more readable when moving along in the database manually (which is mongodb with doctrine mongodb odm here ) - so mostly lazyness.. But what I dont understand right now is, how I can tell the constant's value to be a binary value?

Comment: Very easy! Just take the numbers that are stored in a single bit (powers of 2): 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. For instance, activating flag b and c would result in a bit series of 01100, that can be passed around as 6. It's actually really easy to store/handle, you just have to get used to it.

Comment: I guess this is not what you meant, but basically it works: http://pastie.org/2541980 - From your link, the userSettings should be stored into 1 binary variable which is built out of a binary OR when the user changes it.. is it even possible to store binary values in mongodb (with doctrine?)

Comment: Not exactly what I meant no. You're not actually working with binary values, just the numbers representing them. So `const TYPE_USER_MESSAGE_NEW = 1; const TYPE_USER_MESSAGE_REPLY = 2;`, etc. Your Settings class will then no longer contain an _array_, but a _number_, which you could view as an array of bits so to speak. So your user settings var_dump would simply be 3. Or 8. Or 49. Catch my drift? :)

Comment: Just read up a bit on bitwise operators and stuff. You'll get it :)

Comment: thank you Rijk, I'm getting the idea :) Still need to test and figure it out how to make this a bit more usable and understandable by others ;)